# TextToSpeech throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, google-text-to-speech

I'm writing recycler view which contains editable list of words. ViewHolder for RecyclerView contains 2 objects: editText and sound image icon. My idea is that when I push sound icon, I expect to hear the pronunciation of the word, which I'm realizing with the help of SDK's TextToSpeech class. To reduce amount of code I've created the follow class;

```
public class SpeechController {

private String pronounce;
private Context context;

public TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context,
        new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });

public SpeechController(Context context, String pronounce) {
    this.context = context;
    this.pronounce = pronounce;
}

public void speakOut() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        tts.speak(pronounce, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    } else {
        tts.speak(pronounce, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

Then I create instance of this class in my adapter's onBindViewHolder method for recyclerView like that:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (mGroupsVc != null) {
        GroupVc current = mGroupsVc.get(position);
        holder.nameView.setText(current.getNameGroup());
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SpeechController mSpeechController = new SpeechController(holder.nameView.getContext(),
                        holder.nameView.getText().toString());
                mSpeechController.speakOut();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
        holder.nameView.setText("No Word");
    }
}
```

My application is get compiled but when I'm trying to click sound button NullPointerException appears and gives reference to these operators in both classes:

```
SpeechController mSpeechController = new SpeechController(holder.nameView.getContext(),
                        holder.nameView.getText().toString());


public TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context,
```

I know the meaning of this Exception but I don't where I'm getting wrong with the initialization of object. I need your help to define it. Below I affix the complete error-logcat

```
03-14 17:48:52.168 21719-21719/com.hfad.singleton E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:606)
                                                                    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:582)
                                                                    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:567)
                                                                    at com.hfad.singleton.groupsActivityController.SpeechController.<init>(SpeechController.java:14)
                                                                    at com.hfad.singleton.adapter.GroupsVcAdapter$1.onClick(GroupsVcAdapter.java:52)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After initialising the SpeechController object in the adapter:

```
SpeechController mSpeechController = new SpeechController(holder.nameView.getContext(),
                    holder.nameView.getText().toString());
mSpeechController.speakOut();
```

You call its method `speakout()` which tries to access the variable `tts`:

```
tts.speak()
```

This object has not been initialised in the adapter's current scope, so throws an NPE.

So what you **could** do is initialise the `tts` object in the constructor of the SpeechController object:

```
private String pronounce;
private Context context;
public TextToSpeech tts;

public SpeechController(Context context, String pronounce) {
this.context = context;
this.pronounce = pronounce;
tts = new TextToSpeech(context,
    new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This will fix the NPE crash as `tts` is no longer null in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `TTS` after context is set .

```
 public TextToSpeech tts ;
private Context context;
public SpeechController(Context context, String pronounce) {
    this.context = context;
    this.pronounce = pronounce;
    initTTS();
}
private void initTTS(){
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```